# Pandas, Keyerror Column not in index

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting `KeyError: "['Business Unit'] not in index`

based on line `b = HR[a.iloc[:,0]]`

I've checked `HR`  for column `Business_Unit` using `list(HR.columns.values)` and it exists.

What am I  missing here?

More code:

```
for row in range(len(list_dataframes)):
    a = data_column[data_column['Name of Dataframe']== list_dataframes.iloc[row,0]]
    b = HR[a.iloc[:,0]]
```

`a` dataframe does contain `Business Unit` here is a sample of the data in dataframe `a`:

```
                              0 Name of Dataframe
0    ï»¿"Account"                   Diamond Website 
1    Account User                   Diamond Website 
2    Action                         Diamond Website 
3    Created On                     Diamond Website 
4    Deleted On                     Diamond Website 
36   Business Number                Diamond Website 
37   Business Unit                  Diamond Website
```

Answer (score 0):

If your post does not contain typos, your code uses `Business Unit` (with a space), but your dataframe uses `Business_Unit` (with an underscore).